# How do i run Perl command from a makefile

Tags: perl, makefile

I want to run command `perl -MConfig -e 'print $Config{archlib}'` in my makefile and use the location it returns in my `LDFLAGS`. Can anyone help me. I tried different ways using `$(shell ..)` but it did not work

I want to do something like this

```
PERLPATH = $(shell 'perl -MConfig -e "print $Config{archlib}"')
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `$Config{archlib}` should already be available at makefile var `$ARCHLIB` or something like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a Makefile, you have to use double dollar signs if you do not want `make` to interpret them. Avoid double quotes, though, as shell would try to expand variables.

```
PERLPATH = $(shell perl -MConfig -e 'print $$Config{archlib}')
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba it worked for me. I used it like this LDFLAGS += -L./../../build -L$(PERLPATH)/CORE

Comment: one question why do i need to use $(PERLPATH) and not just $PERLPATH. Can you explain the difference.

Comment: @newguy: That is the Makefile syntax.

Comment: ok. i have another mistake than i am doing this INCS += -I$HOME/include -I/usr/include. I will have to change it to $(HOME) i think.

Comment: @newguy: Use `$(HOME)` or `$$HOME`.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify what you mean by *it did not work*.  When asking questions you should always provide the exact command you ran and the exact error that was generated.

However, the problem with your invocation of `shell` is that you're quoting the entire command.  You should just put the command you want to run directly, as you would type it to the shell prompt.  That means you need to either use single-quotes around the shell script, or escape the `$` from the shell.  Then you need to escape `$` from make, by doubling it.  Basically, you should get the command to run properly at your shell prompt then simply cut and paste that exactly that string into the `shell` function.  Then change every instance of `$` to `$$` to escape it from make.

Also you should (for efficiency) use `:=` instead:

```
PERLPATH := $(shell perl -MConfig -e 'print $$Config{archlib}')
```

And of course you want to use this path variable:

```
LDFLAGS += -L$(PERLPATH)/CORE
```